# How to improve the IPC through the pipes?

Tags: python, ipc, subprocess, pipe

Help improve this code - the IPC through the pipes. I think that use function **replace("\n", "\()")** is unsafe, because string **pickle.dumps(data)** may include symbols **"\()"**. Are there any sensible ways?

Main module:

```
import subprocess, pickle
data=["A","B","C"]
data = pickle.dumps(data).replace("\n", "\\()")
p=subprocess.Popen(["python", "server.py"],stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout= subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(input=data)
print stdout
```

server.py:

```
import pickle,sys
s=sys.stdin.readline()
data = pickle.loads(s.replace("\\()", "\n"))
sys.stdout.write(str(data))
```

Comment: Why are you try to replace newlines?

Comment: String s include newlines symbols. And we use function readline()...

Comment: It seems like it would be better to send the size of what you're about to send then read exactly that amount on the other side.